# How do I copy an image from one div to another div by the image ID

Tags: jquery, image, copy, jquery-ui-tabs

I have 3 tabs. On the first tab is a link that opens the second tab. The second tab has a series of images. What I am trying to achieve is when a user clicks on any of the images in the second tab, that image is copied back to the div where the user first clicked to open this tab. Every thing I have tried so far has failed. I need to know the id of the clicked image and copy this image. If the user then clicks another image  it would  copy that one as well.

```
<div id="demoTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#bike">Bike</a></li>
        <li><a href="#coach">Coach</a></li>
        <li><a href="#truck">Truck</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="coach">
    <div id="firstDiv">
        <img src="assets/img/english/calltoadventure.png" id="imgone" class="theImage" value="Copy"/> 
        <br>
        <img src="assets/img/english/cinemastudies.png" id="imgtwo" class="theImage" value="Copy"/>
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <img src="assets/img/english/calltoadventure.png" id="img19" class="theImage" value="Copy"/> 
        <br>
        <img src="assets/img/english/cinemastudies.png" id="img20" class="theImage" value="Copy"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bike">
    <div id="secondDiv">
        <a href="#coach" class="open-tab" data-tab-index="1">
        <img src="assets/img/bike.png" id="english"/></a></div>
    </div>  

    <div id="truck"><img src="assets/img/truck.jpg"/></div>

</div>

</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $selectedOption =""; //the option user clicks on which determins which tab to open
    var $theDiv = "";        // the div where the image to copy resides
    var $thecallingDiv = ""; // the div where the image is to be placed
    var $selectedImage = ""; // the image the user selects

    $('#demoTabs').tabs({ active: 0 });

    $('.open-tab').click(function (event) {
        $selectedOption = $(this).children('img').attr('id');
        $thecallingDiv = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');

        $('#demoTabs').tabs("option", "active", $(this).data("tab-index"));
    });

    $("img.theImage").on("click",function() {  
        // get the id of the image selected
        $subjectImage = $(this).attr('id');

        // get the id of the closest div
        $theDiv = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');


        $($selectedImage).clone().attr('id',$selectedImage).append($thecallingDiv);

    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: *On the first tab is a link that opens the second tab*. Why? Why do you have a link on the first tab to open the second tab? Can't you just open the second tab by clicking on it? Also, in your code your `li`s are *bike*, *coach*, *truck*, and your divs are *coach*, *bike*, *truck*. which is the correct order?

Comment: @scaramouche I had moved them around that was the only reason the div names are out of order. The result is what what I wanted. The link is needed because when I finalise the content for the first tab there will be links (calling the relevant tabs). For example, link = english, link=science, link=poetry. I would then have 3 tabs english, science, poetry. When the user clicks on a link it takes them to that tab that will have the books they can choose for that category. It then place an image of that book back on the calling page (div).

Comment: It is early days and and the look and feel keeps changing from the clients end. I started without needing jquery at the last minute they mandated jquery. Throwing my original wireframe out the window. I have no active knowledge of jquery and thought it would be a doddle (more fool me). I have since been given that they will not change anything else going forward. I should be charging them for this but they are a not-for-profit org who were desperate (probably why they asked me). I hope this adds clarity. Once again I cannot thank enough for you very quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using jQueryUI's tabs.

If so, fix your html structure because it does not comply with that libraries proposed structure.

All tou have to do is clone the clicked image into the desired div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const secondDiv = $('#secondDiv')

    $('#demoTabs').tabs({ active: 0 });

    $('.open-tab').click(function (event) {
      $('a[href="#coach"]').click()
    });

    $('#coach img').click(event => {
      secondDiv.append($(event.target).clone())
      console.log(`${$(event.target).attr('id')} copied to first tab`)
    });
});
```

```css
img{cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css'/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div id="demoTabs">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#bike">Bike</a></li>
      <li><a href="#coach">Coach</a></li>
      <li><a href="#truck">Truck</a></li>
  </ul>
 <div id="bike">
      <div id="secondDiv">
          <a href="#" class="open-tab" data-tab-index="1">Open 2nd tab</a>
          <br>
          
      </div>
  </div>  
  
  <div id="coach">
      <div id="firstDiv">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=1" id="imgone" class="theImage" value="Copy"/> 
          <br>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=2" id="imgtwo" class="theImage" value="Copy"/>
      </div>
      <div id="myDiv">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=3" id="imgthree" class="theImage" value="Copy"/> 
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="truck"></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Wow! That was a fast response. I cannot thank you enough. I had tried different things and all failed. Thanks heaps Scaramouche!

Comment: Thanks heaps @Scaramouche! And it was slack of me for not pasting the complete html. I will remember next time to format as though it is all the html. Thanks for pointing this out.